# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with multiple threads

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, exc-bad-access

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue();
tiltManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(
    CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical, 
    toQueue: queue, 
    withHandler: {
                    motion, error in

                    var x = motion.gravity.x;
                    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(x * 9.8), -9.8);

                    println(x);   
                 })
```

Although most of the time it works, sometimes there is EXC BAD ACCESS error with self.physicsWorld.gravity(does not occur everytime when it's run) which is very strange. I am also running this CoreMotion manager on another thread(I'm very new to threading and have almost no knowledge of it), which I suspect is what is causing this EXC BAD ACCESS.

Comment: Maybe the que queue is being relesead? I don't know if startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(_:toQueue:withHandler:) retains it.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that with threading, threads are independent and asynchronous in time from each other. If one thread releases something the other thread requires, the second thread will fail, but the reason won't always be clear.

Comment: A good place to start is: edit your build scheme by going to Run->Diagnostics and enabling zombies.  If it's a problem with something being released, that should give you better information.  (Remember to turn it off again after your testing is finished!)